# Similar phrases to a "situation close to life"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, grammaticality-in-context, colloquial-language, literature

In Czech, when we talk about a scene in a book/movie that reminds us of our own lives, we say it is very "from life" (*ze života*).

What are the ways to express such feeling in English?

Comment: There is a phrase [*art imitates life*](https://www.google.com/search?q=art+imitates+life).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say the film is **realistic** or that it shows **scenes from everyday life** or depicts **the familiar** or that it is **true to life**.

The last is probably the closest translation.